# Expressing a time series in more detailed time interval using mathematical approximations

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima

I have a time series with a dependent variable (electricity consumption) measured on a daily basis. I have also an independent variable (unemployment) measures in monthly intervals. I want to use an ARIMAX type scenario analysis to see the impact of changes in future unemployment to the electricity consumption. First I want to build a model of electricity consumption with the unemployment as the independent variable but I want to use the time series on the daily basis.

What should I do to transform the unemployment on a daily basis? I cannot find data of unemployment on a daily basis since it is reported by the statistical service only in monthly intervals.

Idea 1) Divide the monthly unemployment rate with the number of days in a specific month. It does not sound good to me.

Idea 2) Produce a polynomial interpolation (spline) in the monthly series of unemployment and create continuous smooth approximation of the unemployment each day of the month.

What do you think is the best idea? DO you have any other ideas to propose on how to tackle the problem?